# Displaying a specific sub-category's posts from wp_query

Tags: posts, wp-query, theme-development, twitter-bootstrap, media-modal

I have a modal category and in my modal category i have three sub-categories in it. Here is the structure of my modal category.

```
-Modal
  -Water Pumps
  -Water Heaters
  -Electrical
```

Here, i want to only get a post from my water pumps sub-category from my Modal category and to be displayed in my modal. Here is my code where it displays all that has a category name of modal, how can i restrict it to category name modal and sub-category of water pumps

```
<div id="myModal38" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
<?php $args1 = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'category_name' => 'modal',
                    'posts_per_page' => '1',
                );
    $modalPost = new WP_Query( $args1 );
    if( $modalPost->have_posts() ) : 
?>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <?php while ( $modalPost->have_posts() ) : $modalPost->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>       
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<!-- Modal -->
```

Comment: If you want to just get a single specific post you can use get_post(), otherwise you will have to use a tax_query. What template is this on?

Comment: custom made template sir, what do you mean sir ? how can i do it ? how can i use get_post ?

Comment: @Nath Hello sir how can i do that ? can you answer my question using the  get_post you said ?

Comment: Well which do you want? It's not clear to me what you are asking in your question. Do you want a single specific post? Or ALL posts from 'Water Pumps' category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by manipulating the `WP_Query` arguments like below-

```
$idObj = get_category_by_slug('water-pumps-modal'); 
$args1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    /*'category_name' => 'modal',*/
    'category__in' => array( $idObj->term_id ), // Take only IDs of the categories
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
);
```

Comment: do you mean i would replace water pumps by its ID? how can i get the ID? sorry sir i am a very beginner in wp

Comment: Check my updated code. @JcJohn

Comment: hello sir, i didn't get any post. here is the slug from my category water-pumps-modal

Comment: Now try the updated code. Actually you ned to provide the slug to `get_category_by_slug `, which has now been provided by me. So now if you run the code you'll get the post. @JcJohn

Answer (score 0):

```
'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'Category',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array('Modal' => 'water-pumps')   
                        ),
                    ),
        );
```

Using it inside the args array will allow you to display content specific from the subcategory, in this case 'water-pumps' of the category 'Modal'

This is an alternative to above answer.